# C# Get SQL Logs

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, logging

I've searched extensively for help but have found nothing, what I'm trying to do is backup the SQL log files (Management > SQL Server Logs) to a csv or text file.

Is there a way to do this with C#?

Comment: Are you writing **SQL** (structured query language) and really mean Microsoft **SQL Server** (the actual product) by this? If yes: please add `sql-server` tag to make this clear. If not: **what** database system is this for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187885(v=sql.105).aspx

> View the SQL Server error log by using SQL  Management Studio or any
>   text editor. By default, the error log is located at Program
>   Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.n\MSSQL\LOG\ERRORLOG and ERRORLOG.n
>   files.

So you can use the [Directory.EnumerateFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383458.aspx) class to enumerate the files and [File.ReadAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext.aspx) to read the text from each file.

Comment: Thanks Stuart,

Do you know if SQL has a registry key that holds the error log location, this is the main think i've had trouble finding. Thanks.

Comment: I also found `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY(‘ErrorLogFileName’);`

Comment: That will do the trick nicely :) thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to get the error log path via the SQL Server SMO assembly:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;

namespace SQLLogsToText
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string errorLogPath = null;

            using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Integrated Security=SSPI; Data Source=(local)\SQLEXPRESS"))
            {
                var serverConnection = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection(sqlConnection);
                var server = new Server(serverConnection);
                errorLogPath = server.ErrorLogPath;
            }

            if (errorLogPath != null)
            {
                // Enumerate Files
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should put SqlConnections in a `using` construct to ensure they are properly disposed..

Comment: Thanks Jason, a very good solution but with my current plans I'll find it far easier using a SQL query (SELECT SERVERPROPERTY(‘ErrorLogFileName’)) to find the location, i can then copy the files as necessary.

Comment: @Dan Hall - using SERVERPROPERTY is a good solution...that way you don't have any dependencies on the SMO assemblies.

Comment: @stuartd - Thanks. I updated the code to use the using construct.